# google app engine: display images in place

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am following the Blobstore example in *Programming Google App Engine 2e*.

In that example, the **home.html** gives links to the user uploaded images, and when click the links, images show in another new window. Is there any way to display these images in place? Are there any examples on the Internet?

Below are some code segments from the book:
in the home.html, the code that provides links to these images are:

```html
<a href="/view?key={{ upload.key() }}"> {{upload.blob.filename}} </a>
```

the code in the request handler that handles image view request:

```py
class ViewHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
def get(self):
    upload = get_upload(self.request.params.get('key'),
                        users.get_current_user())
    if not upload:
        self.error(404)
        return

    self.send_blob(upload.blob)
```

In this way, when click the link in home.html, it directs to a new window and displays the image.
I want to find some way to display the image in place rather than in a new window.

Comment: too less information to answer. Give a little more information (which language you use, paste some code).

Answer (score 0):

I use image.get_serving_url() to generate a thumbnail upon user's uploading of the image and store it in the datastore. And then I just need to use

```html
<img src="">
```

in the html to display it.